Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated
My rs part:
#[derive(Accounts)] pub struct CreateLottery<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = 4 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 8, // 8 for account discriminator and rest for fields
        seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &master.last_id.to_le_bytes(),
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [MASTER_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub master: Account<'info, Master>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>, }

#[account] pub struct Lottery {
    pub id: u32,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub ticket_price: u64,
    pub last_ticket_id: u32,
    pub winner_id: Option<u32>,
    pub claimed: bool, }

on ts:
    const [lotteryPda, lotteryBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(lotterySeed),Buffer.from((lastId + 1).toString())],
      anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    );


    console.log('Lottery PDA: ', lotteryPda.toBase58());

    const ticketPrice = new anchor.BN(1000000000);
    let lotteryAccount;
    try {
      lotteryAccount = await program.account.lottery.fetch(lotteryPda);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Lottery account does not exist. Creating it now.');
      // If it doesn't exist, create the lottery account
      let tx2 = await program.rpc.createLottery(ticketPrice, {
        accounts: {
          lottery: lotteryPda,
          master: masterPda,
          authority: payer.publicKey,
          systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [payer],
      });

      await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction(tx2);
      lotteryAccount = await program.account.lottery.fetch(lotteryPda);

Doubled checked the last id , it's working as suppose.
passing the right program id of my current program. All is good
Why do I get this?

Error: AnchorError caused by account: lottery. Error Code:
ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint
was violated. Program log: Left: Program log:
C8dbR5u1T6PGssMMU1X1DwoeX8Agy1dSi5xtH5bp9h2r Program log: Right:
Program log: 6sMVsQoY5WsMxmjxn8SxSDKYzy1zuUGEBSX3LTpVDa3s


You migh be deriving the lottery address incorrectly,
Try this and check whether the tests pass
 const [lotteryPda, lotteryBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(lotterySeed), new BN(lastId + 1).toBuffer("le", 8) ],
      anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    );

